# How do I copy firmware to /lib/firmware in Ubuntu Core 22 LTS?

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-core, firmware

My problem is with Ubuntu Core 22 LTS. It's running on my rasp3b+ with *tvheadend*. My *terratec h7* needs a firmware file that I have on hand. My problem is that I can't copy the firmware file to `/lib/firmware/.

```
cp dvb-usb-terratec-h7-az6007.fw /lib/firmware/
cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-terratec-h7-az6007.fw': Read-only file system
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/writable-paths.5.html for an explanation of why you have a read-only filesystem and how to install your file the correct way on Ubuntu Core.